# Exception in initializer error in Wiengine

Tags: android, game-engine

Hi I am trying to load my game on Samsung Galaxy Nexus but it give me an exception

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load xml2: findLibrary returned null

from the exception it seems like there is a library which is unable to load. I am loading all the libraries , all the so files are loaded on other devices correctly but it in unable to load in Galaxy Nexus.
My gut feeling says that Wiengine doesn't support ICS but on the other hand I may be wrong as I am pretty much new to game development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the libxml2 is not found, you probably not include necessary library in your project or reference broken.

Try latest wiengine version, and now it goes to open source: https://github.com/stubma/WiEngine. build a latest wiengine and it should has such problem.